# "Load data infile" inserting into database

Tags: mysql, powershell, csv, bulkinsert

I am having a problem with loading a CSV file into MySQL database. Here is my code:

```psh
$sql =@"
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:\\03-06-44.txt' INTO TABLE monitor.app_meter CHARACTER SET UTF8           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES  
(name,total,@var1,@var2)  
SET start = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%m/%d/%Y %r'),end = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%m/%d/%Y %r')

"@


$MysqlQuery.CommandText = $sql
$MysqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I get **Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Fatal error encountered during command execution."** whatever I do.

But when I run the same `load data infile` block with actual values from CSV inside phpmyadmin, everything works fine. The data is inserted into MySQL.

If I replace `load data infile` with normal `insert` then the code is executing fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
Allow User Variables=True
```

into the MySQL DB connection string:

```psh
$Conn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=mysqlserver.localhost;DATABASE=xxx;" +
                         "UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;Allow User Variables=True"
```

and the code executed properly and inserted the CSV data into MySQL.